# Magento 2 how to get 2 free shipping

Tags: magento2.2, shipping, shipping-methods, magento2.2.3

Magento 2 how to get 2 free shipping setting Amount?

> 1 is for `usa` standard
>
> 2 is for `aus` standard

Please help

Comment: Do you want 2 free shipping? One for USA and one for AUS? What about other countries?

Comment: YES! if can do it, we want other countries can do it too^^ @SukumarGorai

Answer (score 0):

You can try the webshopapps matrixrate where you can manage the shipping price and labels country wise. Check the extension its free.

http://webshopapps.com/row/magento-2-extensions/wsa-standalone/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

In place of shipping price you need to put 0 and in place of shipping label you need to write "USA Standard", "AUS Standard" and so on.

Comment: this is only 30 Day FREE Plugin ,Not a magento 2 completed solution. @SukumarGorai

Comment: 30 Day Free Plugin is for ShipperHQ not matrixrate. Check the link.

Comment: do you have other solution, like edit the code?@SukumarGorai

Comment: When you have already an extension then why you need other solution. This is very easy to implement.

Comment: we hope is USA is setting free shipping Amount is $10, AUS amount is $20. it can do that?thank you^^ @SukumarGorai

Comment: Yes this extension also allows you to set different shipping amount for different countries. you can also set multiple shipping methods for same country like, subtotal $0-$499: shipping cost will 10$ and above 500 it will be free. This type of configurations are already there in the extension.

Comment: i getting new problem https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224059/magento-2-checkout-page-summary-sidebar-not-update-the-total?noredirect=1#comment311191_224059 @SukumarGorai